# emacs evil mode moving up

Tags: emacs, evil-mode

I have a weird behaviour with evil-mode in emacs.
When I move up by 'k' or up arrow after empty line I jump by 2 lines.
Something like evil-mode after empty line ignores one line above.
With moving down there is no problem at all.
GNU Emacs 24.3.1 (Arch Linux) evil-mode from elpa.
Just starting with emacs so I have only basic .emacs and only a few extensions.

Thanks a lot for help.

Comment: I created a bug report: https://bitbucket.org/lyro/evil/issue/353/move-up-from-empty-line-jumps-two-lines